# How do I find the list in a list of lists wherein the first occurence of a certain atom is found?

Tags: list, prolog

So what I am looking for is basically this:

```
findatom(A, L, NL), 
with inputs: 
A = -,  %sought after atom
L = [[1,2,3], [2,-,3], [1,2,3]] %list of lists 
and then it outputs: 
NL = [2,-,3] %the first list containing the sought after atom
```

how would this be possible? I tried this:

```
    /*Append something (dummy variable) with the first occurence of the
 sought after atom (L), then output everything after the found atom (L). */

        findatom(L, List, NewList) :-
          append(_, [L|T], List),
          NewList = [L|T].
```

This only works if there's a list existing of atoms, not a list of lists. How could I expand upon this to make it work for a list of lists?

Comment: Although append can be used in the most suprising ways, it is not entirely clear to me why you think to use this?

Answer (score 1):

Let's do this one in words: `findatom(A, L, NL)` finds the list `NL` in `L` such that `A` is in it. Let's replace those words with Prolog predicates: `findatom(A, L, NL)` finds the `member` NL of L such that `A` is a member of `NL`.

```
findatom(A, L, NL) :- 
    member(NL, L),     % find an item NL in L
    memberchk(A, NL).  % that contains A
```

The pro of using `memberchk` here is that it is deterministic, so you don't need to worry about getting multiple spurious solutions.